# R glpk compilation error

Tags: r, fedora, glpk

Running Fedora 20 and installed R 3.1 and GLPK through yum.  When trying to install the Rglpk library in R, I'm getting a compilation error:

/bin/sh: line 0: cd:_GLPK: No such file or directory
make: *** (GLPK.ts) Error 1
ERROR: copmliation failed for package 'Rglpk'

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you install libglpk-dev? Search if binaries exist. That is the only information I can infer from the error message.

Comment: You should check to 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594986/installing-rglpk-on-linux/28769027#28769027

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114771/glpk-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-trying-to-install-r-package