# Installing Rglpk on linux

Tags: install.packages

I am trying to install Rglpk using the install.packages command. I am getting this error :
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: GLPK: No such file or directory
make: *** [GLPK.ts] Error 1

The glpk-dev package is already installed :

rpm -qa| grep glpk-dev
glpk-devel-4.40-1.1.el6.x86_64

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Hi what I did was the following as a sudoer

```
cd usr local
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/glpk-4.54.tar.gz
tar xfzv glpk-4.54.tar.gz
mkdir GLPK
./configure
make
make install
```

then download the `Rglpk_0.6-0.tar.gz` and install.package the usual way. It is basically the same as what was done here, but as a sudoer:

Answer (score 1):

I got this fixed by running 'sudo make' and 'sudo make install' instead of 'make' and 'make install'. Not sure if this is good practice, someone else be the judge.

```
cd $HOME
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/glpk-4.65.tar.gz
tar xfzv glpk-4.65.tar.gz
mkdir GLPK
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then run install.packages('Rglpk') from within R.

Answer (score 0):

My experience was the following as a sudoer:

1. install GLPK package: see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Linux_OS
2. install Rglpk:

`# install devtools package beforehand. Or, you can download the Rglpk package manually, and then install in R.`

`# note that the latest version of Rglpk does not work on my Redhat system. Instead, the version 0.6-0 works perfectly.`

`devtools::install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rglpk/Rglpk_0.6-0.tar.gz")`

Testing: in R, try `require(Rgplk)`