# installing Rglpk with RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I'e installed glpk on my linux system but when i install Rglpk with RStudio, i've the following error

- installing *source* package Rglpk ...
  ** package Rglpk correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
  Erreur dans dyn.load("conftest.so") :
  impossible de charger l'objet partagé '/tmp/RtmpKY9Rsd/R.INSTALL7f184a134d81/Rglpk/conftest.so':
  libglpk.so.36: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
  Exécution arrétée
  ** libs
  /bin/bash: ligne 0 : cd: GLPK: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
  make: *** [GLPK.ts] Erreur 1

What mean this error, i forgot or missing a library !!

Answer (score -1):

solution found on
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114771/glpk-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-trying-to-install-r-package/27879535#27879535)

`wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/glpk-4.55.tar.gz

tar xvf glpk-4.55.tar.gz

make a GLPK directory in your local path:

mkdir ~/GLPK

configure within glpk:

cd glpk-4.55

./configure --prefix=$HOME/GLPK

make

make install

cd ..

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/GLPK/lib

export LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/GLPK/lib

export CPATH=$HOME/GLPK/include

download the Rglpk package from cran and extract it:

wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rglpk_0.6-0.tar.gz

tar xvf Rglpk_0.6_0.tar.gz

move the glpk directory into Rglpk/src and rename it to GLPK:

mv glpk-4.55 Rglpk/src/GLPK

now you can install:

R CMD INSTALL Rglpk`