# Unable to install package RGLPK with R Studio Server in AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation, install.packages

I am trying to install the package RGLPK with an AWS EC2 instance which has R Studio 1.3 and R 4.0 running.  I get this result:

```
> install.packages("Rglpk")
Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rglpk_0.6-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 21753 bytes (21 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 21 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Rglpk’ ...
** package ‘Rglpk’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: GLPK: No such file or directory
Makevars:10: recipe for target 'GLPK.ts' failed
make: *** [GLPK.ts] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rglpk’
* removing ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rglpk’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rglpk’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpHmQk09/downloaded_packages’
```

I have found numerous similar errors involving this package.  Such as this:
[GLPK: No such file or directory error when trying to install R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114771/glpk-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-trying-to-install-r-package)

There seems to be 3 or 4 solutions, but they involve sudo commands from the terminal window.  I am in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

In the terminal within R Studio Server:

```
sudo apt install libglpk-dev
```

And back in the console, install the R library:

```
install.packages("Rglpk")
```

Credit: @AdamErickson from this post:
[GLPK: No such file or directory error when trying to install R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114771/glpk-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-trying-to-install-r-package)