# Error in library(FRAPO) : there is no package called ‘FRAPO’

Tags: r, package, r-package

I'm trying to load the FRAPO package in RStudio but I keep getting the error message that it does not exist. During installation I get some warnings that the installation of the package had a non-zero exit status. How can I solve this issue?

[image: 1]

Comment: You are getting a message that FRAPO cannot be installed without its dependency Rglpk. I suggest you install that package first (possibly after tracking down the missing system package:GLPK, and in the future read the error messages more carefully. I also suggest you NOT use pictures for errors. Post text.

Comment: The issue here is installation failure for Rglpk. This seems to be [a common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114771/glpk-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-trying-to-install-r-package). There may be a pre-built package for your Linux installation _e.g._ on Ubuntu you could use `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rglpk`.